# How can I add value from form to div, stacking up the values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a automatic invoice system for my daily worked hours. I want to fill in my clients and any possible feature, then submit that value to another div.

Here's what I have (sorry for the dutch names):

```html
<div class="formworkshop">
  <form action="#" min-width="400 500 600">
    <div class="formfield">
      <input type="text" class="forminput" id="name" style="color:#000;border-color:#e3e3e3;border-radius:4px;font-weight:400" placeholder="Welke klant is dit?" required>
    </div>
    <div class="formfield">
      <input type="text" class="forminput" id="feature" placeholder="Zijn er nog andere features?">
    </div>
    <div class="formfield">
      <button data-element="submit" onclick="showValue()" class="formbutton" id="lekkerbutton" style="color:#000;background-color:#F73548;border-radius:4px;font-weight:400">
        <span>Incasso beginnen</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('lekkerbutton').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
  });
    function showValue(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('klant').innerHTML += name;
    
    
    var feature = document.getElementById('feature').value;
    document.getElementById('support').innerHTML += feature;
  }
</script>
```

Here's the other div where the values are stored:

```
<div id="klant"></div>
<div id="support"></div>
```

for now the output will come looking like this:
(with 1 input being "Client" & "no" and the seconde submitted value being "Client" & "yes")

ClientClient
noyes

I need every value to be on a new line or at least with whitespace in between the values... Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add a `<br>` tag between them.

Comment: Where? The value(s) will be stored like <div id="klant">ClientClient</div> and <div id="support">noyes</div>

Comment: Try this: `<div id="klant"></div> <br> <div id="support"></div>`.

Comment: I don't need the divs to be on a new line. I already have that (as i showed in the output). I need the values to be on a new line. So the id="klant" needs every input value on a new line :)

Comment: Well then in your Javascript try adding `string + "<br>"`.

Comment: That was it. Now i know what to do, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding to to the inner html of each of the divs add to the parent of that div. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/colinah/pen/MWbjYVr

html for outputs:

```
<div id="output">
</div>
```

New showValues function:

```
   function showValue(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var feature = document.getElementById('feature').value;
      
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += `<div id="klant">${name}</div><div id="support">${feature}</div><br />`
  }
```

The new outputs will look like this:

```
<div id="output">
 <div id="klant">name</div>
 <div id="support">feature</div>
 <br />
 <div id="klant">name</div>
 <div id="support">feature</div>
 <br />
 <div id="klant">name</div>
 <div id="support">feature</div>
 <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is basically the answer i was looking for. Because i'm working in a Wordpress website i've now given my own twist to it: 

```
function showValue(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var feature = document.getElementById('feature').value;
    
    var result = document.getElementById('name', 'feature').value;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += name + '\xa0\xa0\xa0' + feature + "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Good to know that you taught me to also use the variables inside the document.getElement with the $. I didn't know that before. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Be sure to use the back tick not quotes while doing that. The back tick is the one below the esc button. Thats something that tricked me up learning that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a string to the end of your name and feature variables or html, I've added a break tag here (and titles to keep your data outputs straight):

```js
document.getElementById('lekkerbutton').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
  });
    function showValue(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('klant').innerHTML += name + '<Br/>';
    
    
    var feature = document.getElementById('feature').value;
    document.getElementById('support').innerHTML += feature + '<Br/>';
  }
```

```css
.formworkshop {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 75%;
padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compressed CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-ogmFxjqiTMnZhxCqVmcqTvjfe1Y/ec4WaRj/aQPvn+I=" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="formworkshop">
  <form action="#" min-width="400 500 600">
    <div class="formfield">
      <input type="text" class="forminput" id="name" style="color:#000;border-color:#e3e3e3;border-radius:4px;font-weight:400" placeholder="Welke klant is dit?" required>
    </div>
    <div class="formfield">
      <input type="text" class="forminput" id="feature" placeholder="Zijn er nog andere features?">
    </div>
    <div class="formfield">
      <button data-element="submit" onclick="showValue()" class="formbutton button primary" id="lekkerbutton" style="color:#000;background-color:#F73548;border-radius:4px;font-weight:400">
        <span>Incasso beginnen</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <h2>Klant</h2>
  <div id="klant"></div>
  <h2>Support</h2>
<div id="support"></div>
</div>
```